# user login with database and facebook

Tags: android, facebook-login

This is my layout
[image]

this is my activity_main

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF4500"
    android:orientation="vertical">  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignIN"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#000080"
        android:onClick="signIn"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="login"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignUP"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#000080"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Sign up"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="OR"
        android:textColor="#ffff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.fbloginsample.MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my MainActivity

```
package com.fbloginsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loginDataBaseAdapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);
        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intentSignUP = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SignUPActtivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);
            }
        });
    }

    public void signIn(View V) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
        dialog.setTitle("Login");
        final EditText editTextUserName = (EditText) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
        final EditText editTextPassword = (EditText) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

        Button btnSignIn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String storedPassword = loginDataBaseAdapter
                        .getSinlgeEntry(userName);
                if (password.equals(storedPassword)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(main);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "User Name or Password does not match",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

While running the app it gives this error.This is the error on my logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fbloginsample/com.fbloginsample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2198)
            at com.fbloginsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.fbloginsample.MainFragment that is not a Fragment
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:606)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5370)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2198)
            at com.fbloginsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:606)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2108)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5370)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2198)
            at com.fbloginsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6021)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.m``ain(ZygoteInit.java:703)`enter code here`
```

I want to login via facebook .This worked fine when I used just for facebook.But once I add login and signup button to main activity and implemented them.I got above error.Is there anyone to help me out?

This is my Fragment class MainFragment

```
package com.fbloginsample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mTextDetails;
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

    private AccessTokenTracker mTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback=new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
           AccessToken accessToken=loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile= Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            displayWelcomeMessage(profile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    };
    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        mTokenTracker=new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

            }
        };
        mProfileTracker=new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
              displayWelcomeMessage(newProfile);
            }
        };
        mTokenTracker.startTracking();
        mProfileTracker.startTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    public void displayWelcomeMessage(Profile profile){
        if(profile!=null){
//            mTextDetails.setText("welcome"+profile.getName());
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        LoginButton loginButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager,mCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Profile profile=Profile.getCurrentProfile();
//        displayWelcomeMessage(profile);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);
    }
}
```

and this is my layout for fragment class:fragment_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_details"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is your `Fragment` class?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity` that is because you are using support Fragments.

**Change this.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

**To this.**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Comment: @war_Hero I think may be he need to change this as fragment class is going to instantiate. can u tell me why not required ?

Comment: thanks i made a silly mistake.Now I need to go to next acitvity(Home activity) once I click the login with facebook button.However this is not working.Can you please help me do this?

Comment: @RameshBista Pass intent when your facebook login process complete that's it.

Comment: @RameshBista Accept the answer if it is helpful to you and solved your problem thanks :).